# Apply error class and show related validation messages for incorrect fields after form submission? angular 2

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, validation

My function for form submission looks like this at the moment:

```
submitListing(value: string): void {
    if(this.newListingForm.valid) {
      console.log("Form Valid");
    } else {
      console.log("Form Invalid");
    }
  }
```

Here I check if my whole form is valid, if not (`else` condition) I want to apply .error class to all invalid fields within this form and show related error messages. I was able to follow [this guide](http://blog.ng-book.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-forms-in-angular-2/) on forms and understand how to achieve this while users enter data in the form, however how can I do this after form is submitted?

Here is example part from the form:

```
<form [ngFormModel]="newListingForm" (ngSubmit)="submitListing(newListingForm.value)">

<input type="text" placeholder="New Title" [(ngModel)]="mainTitleInput" [ngFormControl]="newListingForm.find('mainTitleInput')" id="main-title_input" class="transparent">

<!-- etc.. -->

</form>
```

and related validation code (using FormBuilder) in my app.ts

```
//New Listing Form
this.newListingForm = fb.group({
  'mainTitleInput': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set a field in your class and include it in your condition you use to show error indicators (`*ngIf="!newListingForm.controls['mainTitleInput'].valid && isSubmitted`).

```ts
var isSubmitted: boolean = false;

submitListing(value: string): void {
  this.isSubmitted = true;
  if(this.newListingForm.valid) {
    console.log("Form Valid");
  } else {
    console.log("Form Invalid");
  }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't seem that && isSubmitted condition is working. I try to submit an invalid form and don't see my error div. However if I remove it I do see it while mainTitleInput field is invalid

Comment: Can you please add the code (especially markup) to your question how you want to use it? What strategy do you use to show/hide errors/warnings? Adding/removing classes, `*ngIf`, ...?

Comment: Well, for simplicity think of a div containing text "Error inside it". so ```<div *ngIf="!newListingForm.controls['mainTitleInput'].valid && isSubmitted>Error</div> ```I want to show this div after form submission and if mainTitleInput is invalid. following check works fine, but is done even if form is not summited !newListingForm.controls['mainTitleInput'].valid

Comment: It works for me. In your last comment your code example is missing a `"` before `>Error</div>`. Is it missing in your real code as well?

Comment: Was missing in real code also, however adding it in still didn't do any change :/

Comment: Your question doesn't provide enough information. You could create a plunker and then I could try to debug it. Otherwise I can just guess.

Answer (score 1):

To complete the Günter's answer, you could also leverage the `ngClass` directive to add some classes to display errors. For example with Twitter Bootstrap it would be the `has-error` class:

```
<form [ngFormModel]="companyForm">
  (...)
  <div class="form-group form-group-sm"
       [ngClass]="{'has-error':!companyForm.controls.name.valid}">
    <label for="for" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name</label>

    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input [ngFormControl]="companyForm.controls.name"
             [(ngModel)]="company.name"/>
      <span *ngIf="!companyForm.controls.name.valid"
            class="help-block text-danger">
        <span *ngIf="companyForm.controls.name?.errors?.required">
          The field is required
        </span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: the [ngClass] doesn't seem to work with statement like ``` [ngClass]="{'has-error': !newListingForm.controls['listingNameInput'].valid && isSubmitted} ``` if I remove && isSubmitted than error class is applied, however without form being submited